# TFS Continuous integraton clickonce application

Tags: c#, tfs, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

I am trying to automatic clickonce application deployment throught TFS continuous integration, my build definition has the following steps (It is simplified, for demostring reasons)

[image: Steps]

Get sources: from TFS server

Nuget restore : Restore nuget packages

PowerShell script: Used to add certificate to main project of the solution as below:

```
$password = 'password'
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Security
$cert = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2
$cert.Import("$(CertPath)", $password, [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags]"PersistKeySet")
$store = new-object system.security.cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store -argumentlist "MY", CurrentUser
$store.Open([System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.OpenFlags]"ReadWrite")
$store.Add($cert)
$store.Close()
```

MSBuild: Build the solution file

[image: MSBuild steps]

All runs correctly, but when i trying to open the exe File on the agent Bin/release path, i am having this exception:

[image: Exception]

Please help me.

Comment: Did you verify your version string, as the error message suggests?

Comment: @DanielMann   Did you mean project assembly info? and i put a try-catch on the specific line but the exception is displayed on another site. I saw the .exe details and the file version is ok

Comment: If i open the solution in Visual Studio anb i build it, everything works fine, please help me

Comment: According to your description and screenshot, looks like everything build properly in TFS, no error or warning. Did you just mean you failed to open the .exe file in TFS build agent? Do you have corresponding environment in build agent? Are you able to open .exe file in your local development environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted the agent and made a new compilation and everything worked. Thanks